# Setting Variable to Axios Call

Tags: reactjs, api, promise, return, axios

In React, I am trying to set a variable to an axios call after I return the data.
But, when console logging the variable afterwards, it's a Promise.
How do I get the value from the promise and set it to the variable?

```
    let fourPackProducts = axios.get('URL').then(response => {
    return response.data })
console.log(fourPackProducts)
```

[Console log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jc2MX.png)

Comment: you should use es6 async/await               

var tests = async () => {
    let response = await axios.get('URL');
    console.log(response.data)
}
test();

Answer (score 1):

You did exactly what you are asking to do.  If you want to `console.log` the correct data, chain another then like so,

```
let promiseResponse = axios.get('URL')
  .then(response => response.data)
  .then( data => { console.log( data ); return data });
```

Remember, ajax requests are async, so code after an ajax request not using async handlers will run, the compiler does not stop and wait for the request to complete

Comment: What's use of second then if you can print and return result from first? unnecessary you are adding one more step
let promiseResponse = axios.get('URL')
  .then( response=> { console.log( response.data ); return response.data });

Comment: true, i was just being verbose trying to show that in order to access that variable as a resolved promise, it had to be in the `.then`

Answer (score 0):

You're console logging a promise because `fourPackProducts` *is* a promise. Another part of the issue is that since the promise is asynchronous, the console log is being called before the promise response comes through. To properly set the promise response to a variable, try the following:

```
let promiseResponse;
let fourPackProducts = axios.get('URL').then(response => {
   promiseResponse = response.data;
   console.log(promiseResponse);
   return promiseResponse; 
})
```

Presumably you want to do something with this variable afterward, but if the promise is not yet completed then the variable will be `undefined`. In order to use the variable after it has been set to the promise response, you will need to [chain promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).